# PHP regex to strip out images with a CID in the src tag

Tags: php, regex

I am currently using PHP to parse emails.  I am able to save both attached and embedded images; however, embedded images are given an irritating "CID" source that results in a broken image link.

I want to parse these out completely, but leave images that have actual web addresses associated.

In other words, `<img src = "http://example.com/images/someimage.jpg">` needs to stay.  But, `<img src = "cid:ii_id8bx9qh0_14f205b0a5e7738a">` needs to go.

Now, I could use strops to find the start and end, and that would be okay... except that certain email clients also embed things like width, height, and ID - and they put them in haphazard order.

So, I need a regex that looks for a start of `<img`, that contains `src="cid`, all the way to the end of the image tag.

Bonus points if it's case insensitive.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: ["Regex is not a tool that can be used to correctly parse HTML."](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1344955)

Comment: A large portion of the internet seems to disagree.  Regex is for pattern matching, no?  I'm trying to match a pattern, nothing more.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use `preg_replace`

```
preg_replace('~<img\b[^>]*src\s*=\s*"cid[^"]*"[^>]*>~i', '', $str);
```

or

```
preg_replace('~<img\b[^>]*\bsrc\s*=\s*[\'"]cid[^>]*>~i', '', $str);
```

`i` modifier helps to do a case-insensitive match.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kI8iW1/1)

Comment: Excellent.  That did it!

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon.  Testing further, doesn't always work.

Comment: forget to escape quotes, try now.

Comment: Meant to come back and say that yes, the fix made it work.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use a proper [**tool**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) for this task instead of regex.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html); // load the HTML data

$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach ($xp->query('//img[contains(@src, "cid")]') as $img) {
   $img->parentNode->removeChild($img);
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: So, stupid question time.  How do I then access the updated HTML?

Comment: I get no errors... but I still get the stupid cid images.  Hrm.

Comment: Works for me no problem.